# How to create generic receiver function for slice

Tags: go

```
type slice []T

func (s *slice) remove(element T) []T {

    newSlice := []T{}

    for _, i:= range s {
        if i != element {
            newSlice = append(newSlice, i)
        }
    }
    return newSlice
}
```

I am trying to create a generic receiver func to remove elements from a slice, above the code I am working with, but I am getting **Undeclared Name: T** error..

Comment: You can also check [this go/exp library](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Delete) to manipulate generic slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you haven't defined type `slice` as a generic type. You have just defined it as a slice of type `T` where type `T` doesn't exist.

If you do define `slice` as a generic type, then your approach works:

```
type slice[T comparable] []T

func (s *slice[T]) remove(element T) []T {

    newSlice := []T{}

    for _, i := range *s {
        if i != element {
            newSlice = append(newSlice, i)
        }
    }
    return newSlice
}
```

(Also needed to change `range s` to `range *s`)